# Why is int an invalid argument for FORMAT's second parameter?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am currently trying to obtain the actual result from an average function, but when I use the format function, it is giving me the following error:

> Msg 8116, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
> Argument data type int is invalid for argument 2 of format function

This is my query:

```
SELECT
    a.BillMonthYear
    ,FORMAT (AVG (a.DaysB4Billing), 'n2')
    ,FORMAT (AVG  (a.DaysB4Billing), 2)
    ,COUNT (a.DaysB4Billing) AS 'Number of invoices'
FROM
    (SELECT  
         [CUST_ID]
         ,[PREMISE_ID]
         --,[INV_TRANSACTION_ID]
         ,CONVERT (date, [INV_TRANSACTION_DATE]) AS 'INV_TXN_DATE'
         --,[USG_TRANSACTION_ID]
         ,CONVERT (date,[USG_TRANSACTION_DATE]) AS 'USG_TXN_DATE'
         ,CONVERT (date,[BILL_DATE]) AS 'BILL_DATE'
         ,DATENAME (weekday, bill_date) AS 'BILLWK_DATE'
         ,CONCAT (DATENAME (MONTH, bill_date), ' ', DATENAME (year, bill_date)) AS 'BillMonthYear'
         ,CASE
             WHEN [INV_TRANSACTION_DATE] = [USG_TRANSACTION_DATE] 
                 THEN CAST ([BILL_DATE] - [INV_TRANSACTION_DATE] AS INT)
             WHEN [INV_TRANSACTION_DATE] > [USG_TRANSACTION_DATE] 
                 THEN CAST ([BILL_DATE] - [INV_TRANSACTION_DATE] AS INT)
             WHEN [INV_TRANSACTION_DATE] < [USG_TRANSACTION_DATE] 
                 THEN CAST ([BILL_DATE] - [USG_TRANSACTION_DATE] AS INT)
          END AS 'DaysB4Billing'
         ,[INV_SENDER_NAME]
         ,[INV_TYPE]      
         ,CONVERT (DATE,[SERVICE_START]) AS 'SVC_START'
         ,CONVERT (DATE,[SERVICE_END]) AS 'SVC_END'
         ,[CUST_STATUS]    
         ,[BILL_NO]
         ,[EXCEPTION_STAT1]
         ,[EXCEPTION_STAT2]
         ,[EXCEPTION_STAT3]
         ,[EXCEPTION_STAT4]
         ,[EXCEPTION_STAT5]
         ,[EXCEPTION_STAT6]
         ,[EXCEPTION_STAT7]
         ,[EXCEPTION_STAT8]
         ,[EXCEPTION_STAT9]
         ,[EXCEPTION_STAT10]
         ,[EXCEPTION_DATE]
         ,[INV_STATUS]
         ,[USG_STATUS]
         ,[BILL_STATUS]
         ,[NOTES]
         ,[UPDATE_BY]
         ,[purpose_code]
         ,[original_invoice_number]
         ,[PRIOR_BILL_STATUS]
         ,[EXCEPTION_ALL]
     FROM 
         [B1].[B1].[dbo].[INV_USG_XREF]
     WHERE 
         purpose_code = '00'
         AND bill_date BETWEEN '06-01-2021' AND '06-30-2021') a
GROUP BY 
    a.BillMonthYear
```

The result should be 2.73, but it is giving me error message I described above.  This is when I add the "format (avg (a.DaysB4Billing), 2)" line, and the one above it does pull the data, but it rounds it down to 2 for some reason.

Comment: What about the error don't you understand? We can try to elaborate, however, it is *very* explicit.

Comment: My apologies, I should have mentioned I am not an advanced user, so I am really not understanding how I can get the function to work for me.  The 'a.DaysB4Billing' is the average number of days for a given timeframe.  It is returning a value of 2.00 with the 'format (avg (a.DaysB4Billing), 'n2')' function, but it gives me an error when I add 'format (avg (a.DaysB4Billing), 2)'.

Comment: Yes, and check the 2nd parameter of that attempt that isn't working and the error you are getting: *"Argument **data type int is invalid** for argument 2 of format function."* What about said error aren't you sure on?

Answer (score 3):

It's expecting a format string, not an integer value in that position. Try

```
format (avg (a.DaysB4Billing), 'N')
```

Reference: [Standard numeric format strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings)

Comment: Thanks!  I tried that, but it is giving me a rounded number, it should be 2.73, but it is giving me 2.00

Comment: @GustavoRodriguez Try making `DaysB4Billing` a DECIMAL instead of an INT in your CASE statement. I think the AVG function may be returning an integer value because the input expression type is INT.

Comment: Nice!  I did that, and it worked!  Thanks so much. :)

Answer (score 0):

Your line 4 is passing an integer to the `format` function, which is not supported, hence the error:

```
select
a.BillMonthYear
,format (avg (a.DaysB4Billing), 'n2')
,format (avg (a.DaysB4Billing), 2) -- right here
```

Perhaps you meant to pass something 'n2' or something of the sort?

Seems then that what you need is this:

```
SELECT CAST(ROUND(avg (a.DaysB4Billing), 2,1) as decimal(10,2))
```

`ROUND(2,1)` will actually truncate to the 2nd decimal place since a number different than 0 (1) is specified in the second parameter.

Comment: Thanks for your response.  I added the third line to see if I would obtain what I am looking for but by using the 'N2' it gives a rounded number, when I tried using the fourth line was to see if I can obtain the accurate number which is 2.73.  Maybe I should use a different function?

Comment: Maybe this will do what you need: First truncate rather than round then take 2 decimal places
`SELECT cast(ROUND(avg (a.DaysB4Billing), 2,1) as decimal(10,2))`